# Jupyter Notebook Server Doesn't Start

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I had a well set-up Windows machine with jupter installed and it was running fine. A week later,

```
> jupyter notebook
[I 12:18:13.640 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 5 kernels found
```

And then nothing happens, Ctrl+z also doesn't work. My notebooks aren't running as the server is just not working.

Any way I can resolve the issue? I have a presentation with those notebooks!

Thanks.

Comment: Some times it just takes too much time. how much time did you wait for?

Comment: @KalyanReddy I have waited for more than 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Check if your port: 8888 is not blocked by some other application

Comment: @user1767754 it probably isn't but how can i check that? netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8888 gives nothing. and 8888 is the port for jupyter.

Comment: here is the temporary solution for your presentation, upload it into github and open it there

Comment: @KalyanReddy can't run the code though, i have live data fetching...

Comment: Try to reinstall your jupyter. `conda remove jupyter && conda install jupyter`

Comment: @Sraw I had tried conda update jupyter it just got stuck at Fetching package metadata ... : Similarly the above command is also now stuck at the same step after asking y/n to removing jupyter...:(

Comment: Could you access this url? https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/

Comment: @Sraw yes.................................

Comment: Could you create another environment, and use `pip install jupyter`?

Comment: @Sraw USING conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda ? aNACONDa has jupyter by default right?

Comment: you can create a pure environment by `conda create -n py27 python=2.7`. Just remove `anaconda`.

Comment: @Sraw again the command gets stuck at Fetching package metadata ...

Comment: @Sraw meanwhile this is happening: >jupyter notebook list
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/ :: C:\Users\rafael\Desktop

Comment: I highly recommend you to reboot your computer. It seems you are running a jupyter server you don't remember.

Comment: @sraw all right, i will reboot now, lets see what happens... "server you don't remember" what happened there? did the process get de-linked or something...i don't know much about this stuff :(

Comment: @sraw thanks, after reboot it just worked, could you add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems there is an existed jupyter server with unstable status. So if you are not sure what happened. Just try to reboot your computer.

Second, you can create a pure environment by `conda create -n name python=x.x`. Just remove `anaconda`. And then use `pip install jupyter` to install jupyter.

Comment: Do not use pip to install packages into conda environments, particularly when conda packages are available.